# module definition file data exports

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, dll, linker, dumpbin

I am using a module definition file (.def) in visual studio 2008 to selectively export symbols to generate an import library. According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyx1zcd3.aspx) on MSDN, adding the keyword *DATA* (or *CONSTANT*) after the symbol-name allows one to create data declarations. Regarding this I am running into a few problems. I would appreciate it if somebody could shed should some light on the problem outlined below.

```
class Allocator
{
public:
    static const int size_not_tracked = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    virtual void *allocate(size_t size, size_t align) = 0;
    virtual void *reallocate(void* ptr, size_t size, size_t align) = 0;
    virtual void deallocate(void *p) = 0;
    virtual size_t allocated_size(void *p) = 0;
    virtual size_t allocated() = 0;
};

class MemoryService
{
public:
    static Allocator* GetProcessDefault();
    static Allocator* GetProcessHeap();
    static Allocator* GetNamedHeap(const char* name, bool tracked, bool logged);    
    static Allocator* xml;
};
```

Consider the code above. I wish to export the variable *xml* so that it can be used over a dll boundary. When linking against the resulting import library, it requests the following symbol.

> "public: static class Allocator * MemoryService::xml"
>   (?xml@MemoryService@@2PAVAllocator@@A)

When the symbol is added to the module definition file *without* the *DATA* keyword, it recognizes the symbol but the code using the variables crashes. Linking against a import library that has the symbol annotated as *DATA* doesn't recognize the symbol and gives a (unresolved symbol) linker error instead.

```
EXPORTS
?xml@MemoryService@@2PAVAllocator@@A DATA
```

*'dumpbin /exports'* however list the output illustrated below. The resulting import library, evidently does export the name in question.

```
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 9.00.30729.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Dump of file xxxxx.lib
File Type: LIBRARY    
     Exports    
       ordinal    name    
                  ....
                  ?xml@MemoryService@@2PAVAllocator@@A (public: static class Allocator * MemoryService::xml)
                  ....    
  Summary    
          CF .debug$S
          14 .idata$2
          14 .idata$3
           4 .idata$4
           4 .idata$5
          10 .idata$6
```

Is there a reason why it the linker does not recognize the symbol? Are there any modifications possible which would permit the illustrated code to work?

Comment: You are exporting a *pointer* to the data.  So the client program should be using "static Allocator** xml;"  This is very awkward and all goes away when you use dllexport/dllimport instead of a DEF file.  [More here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/90530).